# How to make a Rails clicked link affect a counter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Within my LinksController I have the following:

```
  def vote
    @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
    @link.votes << Vote.create!(user_id: @link.user_id, link_id: @link.id)
    @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
    @link.save
    redirect_to :root
  end
```

I also have the following routes:

```
           root GET    /                                   links#index
           link_vote GET    /links/:link_id/vote(.:format)      links#vote
      link_link_vote GET    /links/:link_id/link_vote(.:format) links#link_vote
      link_down_vote GET    /links/:link_id/down_vote(.:format) links#down_vote
               links GET    /links(.:format)                    links#index
                     POST   /links(.:format)                    links#create
            new_link GET    /links/new(.:format)                links#new
           edit_link GET    /links/:id/edit(.:format)           links#edit
                link GET    /links/:id(.:format)                links#show
                     PATCH  /links/:id(.:format)                links#update
                     PUT    /links/:id(.:format)                links#update
                     DELETE /links/:id(.:format)                links#destroy
                     GET    /                                   links#index
```

I'm able to hit the route and cause the totalcount to increase and even do the decrease with another method. I'm struggling, however, with hitting the route for link_vote, the first line below:

```
    <td><%= link_to link.url, "http://#{link.url}", link_link_vote_path(link) %></td>
    <td><%= link.title %></td>
    <td><%= link.totalcount %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "UP", link_vote_path(link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "DOWN", link_down_vote_path(link) %></td>
```

My LinksController has the following:

```
 def link_vote
     @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
     @link.votes << Vote.create!(user_id: @link.user_id, link_id: @link.id)
     @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
     @link.save
     redirect_to :root
 end
```

I'm getting the following when I try to load:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/links/119/link_vote":String
```

I've tried putting link_link_vote_path(link) before the hyperlink. Get roughly the same message: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "http://adamswilliamson.name":String.

Am I just using the wrong route or woefully wrong in syntax?

Comment: Syntax of link_to is wrong. Go through doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

The `link_to` helper accepts a `body`, an `url` and the `html_options` options as arguments. You're trying to pass two urls, and the second one is being threated as part of the options argument, the first one isn't a valid path which Rails can work with.

I think what you need is to pass your interpolated url as the body, like:

```
<%= link_to "http://#{link.url}", link_link_vote_path(link) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of things wrong. First I was redirecting back to the root instead of the URL which was keeping it on the page and affecting the counter but I wasn't hitting back and refreshing the page so I updated it to the following:

```
 def link_vote
   @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
   @link.votes << Vote.create!(user_id: @link.user_id, link_id: @link.id)
   @link.totalcount = @link.votes.count
   @link.save
   redirect_to @link.url
 end
```

Then with the prompt about having two urls being passed I was able to fix the Index to be:

```
<%= link_to link.url, link_link_vote_path(link) %>
```

Works. Thanks for the feedback.